# Why does find result in an empty new line within backticks?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

For some reason, resolving a variable name within backticks and double quotes causes an empty new line.

```
search="randomsite";
res="`find /var/www -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -name '${search}'`";
echo $res
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$()` rather than backticks - they are easier to read and nestable...

```
res=$(find /var/www -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -name "${search}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking to know why my example didn't work though.

Comment: Yours doesn't work because you have put ${search} inside single quotes thereby preventing the shell from expanding the variable $search.

Comment: Try running find -name "${search}" at your shell prompt and that will work, whereas find -name '${search}' will not.

Comment: If this has solved your problem and answered your question, please accept my answer so I get a lovely big green tick. Else, please say what is still not correct, and I, or someone else, will try and assist you further. Thank you.